# JSRender - Render a dictionary structure

Tags: jsrender

I have an ajax call that returns this JSON:

```
<ArrayOfActivityModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NSCC.Api.Models">
<ActivityModel>
<ActivityID>9</ActivityID>
<DateEnd>2020-09-02T00:00:00</DateEnd>
<DateStart>2020-09-02T00:00:00</DateStart>
<DateString>September 2, 2020</DateString>
<ScheduleID>2</ScheduleID>
<Summary>one day on Sep 2</Summary>
<Term>Fall Term</Term>
</ActivityModel>
<ActivityModel>
<ActivityID>1</ActivityID>
<DateEnd>2021-01-05T00:00:00</DateEnd>
<DateStart>2020-12-19T00:00:00</DateStart>
<DateString>December 19, 2020 - January 5, 2021</DateString>
<ScheduleID>0</ScheduleID>
<Summary>Christmas Break - no classes</Summary>
<Term>Winter Term</Term>
</ActivityModel>
<ActivityModel>
<ActivityID>8</ActivityID>
<DateEnd>2021-01-13T00:00:00</DateEnd>
<DateStart>2021-01-13T00:00:00</DateStart>
<DateString>January 13, 2021</DateString>
<ScheduleID>2</ScheduleID>
<Summary>Event on January 13, 2021</Summary>
<Term>Winter Term</Term>
</ActivityModel>
<ActivityModel>
<ActivityID>13</ActivityID>
<DateEnd>2021-06-16T00:00:00</DateEnd>
<DateStart>2021-06-16T00:00:00</DateStart>
<DateString>June 16, 2021</DateString>
<ScheduleID>2</ScheduleID>
<Summary>Golf Tournament</Summary>
<Term>Summer Term</Term>
</ActivityModel>
</ArrayOfActivityModel>
```

We want to group the Activities by Term so I used the reduce() function to do so:

```
var act = activities.reduce(function(result, current) {
                result[current.Term] = result[current.Term] || [];
                result[current.Term].push(current);
                return result;
                }, {});
```

The output is this structure:

```
{Fall Term: Array(1), Winter Term: Array(2), Summer Term: Array(1)}
```

I supply this structure to the following JSRender template:

```
var grid = $("#activitiesTemplate").render(act);     
$("#currentActivityGrid").html(grid);


<script id="activitiesTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <table border="1">
    {{props}}
      <tbody>
        <tr><td> 
          {{props tmpl="#activityTemplate" /}}
        </td></tr>
      </tbody>
    {{/props}}
  </table>
</script>

<script id="activityTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  {{>prop}}<br/>

</script>
```

This produces the following output:

```
Fall Term
[object Object]
Winter Term
[object Object],[object Object]
Summer Term
[object Object]
```

I'm stymied on pulling the values from the unnamed Array(s) in the data structure with JSRender. We're looking for:

```
Fall Term
September 2, 2020 -  one day on Sep 2

Winter Term
December 19, 2020 - January 5, 2021 - Christmas Break - no classes
January 13, 2021 - Event on January 13, 2021

Summer Term
June 16, 2021 - Golf Tournament
```

Seems like this should be straightforward but I'm missing something, I've tried {{for}} as well but can't "get at" the arrays that are the "values" of the "keys" (the Terms).

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It seems that your "JSON" is not JSON but XML. You need to convert it into a JavaScript 'object graph' - i.e. a hierarchy of JavaScript objects and arrays, that you can pass to the JsRender render() method. Within the {{props someobject}} tag you use {{>key}} and {{>prop}} to access key (property name) and property value, See https://www.jsviews.com/#propstag

Comment: Take a look at https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvpropstag@load-hash - which uses JsViews, but can give an idea how it would work with JsRender, if you have a dictionary such as moveJb with an array property: languages, and so you have things like {{props}} ...  {^{for prop.languages}} to iterate over the array, in the template. Otherwise, create a jsfiddle with actual sample data, and your attempted template, and I can try to help you complete/correct the template....